# 301 redirect wont work but was working previously /tag/ url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am using the .htaccess file to create 301 redirects.

```
redirect 301 /example/page http://www.example.com
```

the above code has work wonders and has got the job done.

then i got this link in my web crawl errors :

```
http://www.example.co.za/tag/legislative-framework/www.linkedin.com
```

If you put the link in your url it takes you to this link:

```
http://www.example.co.zawww.linkedin.com/
```

This is what my htaccess file looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How do i create a redirect for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is caused by your htaccess or your redirect statement. But if you have wordpress, you should stick with using mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias (`Redirect 301`) because they'll both affect the same URI and you'll get unexpected results:

```
RewriteRule ^example/page/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```